# scanf("%s",&s); y scanf("%s",s); no deberían andar de igual forma?

Tags: c, scanf

tienen idea porque esto no funciona?

```c
char s[] = "hola";
scanf("%s",&s);
```

Si s y &s dan la misma dirección de memoria

```c
printf("%d",&s);→ 77304699
printf("%d",s); → 77304699
```

Osea que `scanf("%s",&s);` y `scanf("%s",s);` debería andar de igual forma.

Comment: Yo veo el resultado igual

Comment: Los arrays decaen a punteros, entonces en este caso si funciona. Pero esto aplica solo con los arrays.

Comment: No hay diferencia en nada, producen exactamente el mismo código esamblador: https://godbolt.org/z/3Yjr5q5x8 **Vs.** https://godbolt.org/z/v1hff7baq

Comment: ¿ Podrías poner un ejemplo que demuestre ese comportamiento que has observado ? Lo que viene siendo un [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Con C al utilizar `scanf()` debes entender que es lo que hace:

> #### Scanf()
>
> Lee los datos formateados de stdin
> Lee datos de stdin y los almacena de acuerdo con el formato de parámetro en las ubicaciones señaladas por los argumentos adicionales. Los argumentos adicionales deben apuntar a objetos ya asignados del tipo especificado por su especificador de formato correspondiente dentro de la cadena de formato.

Esto significa que la `&` es una referencia a la direccion de memoria de una variable "ya asignada" lo que ocurre cuando haces el array `s[]` es declararlo de forma implicita o sea que le dices al preprocesador, ya veras lo que haces tu, te estoy dando el `const char* ("hola\0")` o sea `[5]` caracteres.
Por lo que el compilador despues se traba preguntandote oye `"%s"` significa `char *` y tu me estas dando `char *[5]` no puedo procesar eso!

Como las cadenas de caracteres empiezan con una direccion de memoria y terminan con el caracter `\0` si tu escribes `&` estas dandole literalmente la direccion de memoria de `s` que apunta al principio del array de caracteres (es como si se tratase de un puntero implicito, la diferencia es al declararlos, ya que de forma explicita se almacenan en el stack y no en el heap como cuando llamas `malloc()`) entonces termina siendo un warning para que entiendas que estas queriendo modificar directamente la direccion de memoria. Si como dices... "no te esta dejando" eso es por una configuracion estricta de lo que estes usando, porque se puede; solo que tira warning.

Answer (score -1):

Para imprimir el char necesitas el printf

```
char s[] = "hola";
printf( "%s", s );
```

el scanf se utiliza para pedir datos por pantalla

```
char s[20];
printf( "Introduzca s (20 letras máximo): " );
scanf( "%s",s );
printf(" S es: %s",s);
```

Comment: Siempre intenta responder lo que te solicitan en la pregunta. O espera a ganar los primeros 50 puntos para poder comentar.